# The Coin Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Suppose there is a square room of side $d$ and we draw on the floor a circumference of radius $\frac{1}{5}d$ whose center concur with the center of the square room. If we throw a coin of radius $\frac{1}{10}d$ randomly, which is the probability that the coin doesn't touch the circumference?

We are interested in the following event:

$E$: "Coin doesn't touch the circumference"

The visual representation of the problem is the following:

[image]

**NOTE 1:** There are some points of the floor that can not be the center of the coin because the walls of the room can not be traversed. All this points are ubicated in the pink region of the next picture. (Consequently, the pink region isn't part of the sample space)

[image]

Consequently, we are going to determine which points of the square of side $\frac{8}{10}d$ verify this property:

- If the coin has its center in the green region, then it does not touch the circumference of radius $\frac{1}{5}d$

[image]

**NOTE 2:** All the points of the green region verify the previous condition.

We are going to calculate the area of the square of side $\frac{8}{10}d$ and the green region:

$A_{square} = (\frac{8}{10}d)^2 = \frac{64}{100}d^2 $

$A_{green} = \pi(\frac{1}{10}d)^2+[(\frac{8}{10}d)^2-\pi(\frac{3}{10}d)^2] = d^2(\frac{\pi}{100}+\frac{64}{100}-\frac{9\pi}{100})= (\frac{64-8\pi}{100})d^2$

Therefore, the probability of the event $E$ is the following:

$P(E)=\frac{A_{green}}{A_{square}} = \frac{\frac{64-8\pi}{100}d^2}{\frac{64}{100}d^2} = \frac{64-8\pi}{64} = \frac{8-\pi}{8} = 0.6073009183... $

Is this reasoning correct? I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your reasoning. I didn't check the arithmetic/algebra though.

Comment: @insipidintegrator - is that true? The sample space for the coins center can only be in the region described...

Comment: Your analysis/approach also makes sense to me.  I also would have examined the relative area of the concentric circles.

Comment: Your reasoning and your calculation are correct as far as I can see. It would be useful to say what parts you're not 100% sure about, since it's very difficult to post an answer otherwise, and the question then goes into the list of "unanswered questions". (About 20% of the questions on this site are marked as "unanswered", although a lot of those actually have answers which people left as comments.)

Comment: Sorry @SuzuHirose. Next time I will try to be more specific about my doubts.

Comment: There is no need to apologise, just not sure how to answer you since the work looks OK.